# SOS AWS S3 Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am trying to restrict access to my AWS S3 Bucket, so that only a few domains, 1 IP-address and AWS Lambda functions will have access to it.

This is what I have written, but it is not working :-(

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "httpRefererPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRequestsReferred",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://example.com/*",
                        "https://example.herokuapp.com/*",
                        "https://dfgdsfgdfg.cloudfront.net/*"
                    ]
                },
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "219.77.225.296"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyRequestsReferred",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectAcl"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://example.com/*",
                        "https://example.herokuapp.com/*",
                        "https://dfgdsfgdfg.cloudfront.net/*"
                    ]
                },
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "219.77.225.296"
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

What have I written wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your policy says:

**ALLOW** `GetObject` access from an (invalid) IP address if the request was referred from certain websites.

**DENY** `GetObject` access if the request is *not* from Lambda and is *not* an (invalid) IP address and was *not* referred from certain websites.

So, the first thing is that `IpAddress` needs to be in CIDR notation, so you should use:

```
"aws:SourceIp": "219.77.225.296/32"
```

Second, there is nothing in this policy that is granting access to the Lambda function (since it is *not* on the IP address in the ALLOW statement). Also, your method of granting access looks unlikely to work. I would recommend **granting access to the IAM Role being used by the Lambda function**.

I would suggest you only create `ALLOW` statements, and give access to each source independently. If you want to grant access based on `referer` OR `IpAddress` OR Lambda, you'd need:

- ALLOW based on `referer`
- ALLOW based on `IpAddress`
- ALLOW based on `Lambda` (You'll need to do this by permitting access from the IAM Role used by the Lambda function)

Only use DENY if you need to override a permission that was previously granted via ALLOW. It is best to avoid DENY if possible, to keep things easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if i will not use the Deny people from outside my website can see there pictures. I want that only people that currently in my website can see there pictures.

Comment: All objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. People can only access the objects if you have some policy (Bucket Policy, IAM Policy, or permissions on the object) that **specifically grant access**. If you are saying that people outside the above ALLOW policies can access your objects, then you need to track down what is granting them access and remove it immediately!

Comment: I have a file upload button in my website each user can upload a file and that file automatically gets acl public-read permission.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to provide public access to the files, then you should modify whatever is granting that access. If the upload function is putting the permissions on each object individually, you'll need to remove those permissions from the existing files. Trying to craft a `DENY` policy for everyone except several use-cases is a difficult and potentially error-prone way to control access.